# How to update array of data on a specific row using radio button? Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am making a backend quiz app where backend user will change the answer or choice.

> I would like the radio button to set value as **1** when I'll change
>   or update my answer or choice and replaced the former choice to **0**.

I have `answers` table and this is my example of inputs

> `correct` field is the field I would like to update everytime the user will change choice or answer
>   . The expected result is, if I update the correct choice then the former choice will be replaced by `0`. And the new choice or answer will be updated as `1` in **correct** field

```
id | answers | question_id | correct
1  |   A     |     1       |   0
2  |   B     |     1       |   1
3  |   C     |     1       |   0
4  |   D     |     1       |   0
5  |  F.1    |     2       |   0
6  |  F.2    |     2       |   1
```

Update Model - so I can already update or change array of answer texts but I am not familiar about update and replacing value of ids.

```
public function update_post(){

        $id = $this->input->post('answers_textId');

        $data = $this->input->post();

            for($i = 0; $i < (count($data['id'])); $i++){

                $batch[] = array(
                'id' => $data['id'][$i],
                'answer' => $data['answer'][$i],
                'correct' => $data['correct_id'][$i]
                );
            }

        return $this->db->update_batch('answers', $batch, 'id');
}
```

In View

This is the id

```
<input type="hidden" name="answers_textId" value="<?php echo $answer['question_id']; ?>" />  //For the question_id field

<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $answer['id']; ?>" /> //For the id or PK
```

> This is my radio button, its element are `opt_1`, `opt_2`, and so on.

```
<input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="opt_<?php echo $answer['id']; ?>" value="1">
```

> This is my text field or text box

```
<h5>Choice: </h5><input type="text" name="answer[]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $answer['answer']; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you are the guy from yesterday :)

i am assuming you have send data to you controller

you need question_id and id (from answer table)

first **update all correct = false or 0 where question_id = $id (id of question)**

this will make all correct for the question 0, example question_id = 1 has 4 answers, it will set all 4 answers correct = 0

and then **update correct = 1 where id = answer_table_id(PK) and question_id = $id (id of question)**

this will update the answer you made change to correct = 1
you dont need question_id for this, becuase id (answer table pk) is unique

so now try to make the function.